# Does Python's pathlib have simple methods to convert between paths and files?

Tags: python, pandas, pathlib

The objects in pathlib are paths and I know not all paths can resolve to files. But I would expect an easy way to convert an acceptable path to a file. I've seen that there are special methods to read from or write to a text file (getting string objects) or to and from .json files. I want to read and write csv files to DataFrames using Pandas.

Surely it's not all special pathlib methods. There must be an easy way I've managed to miss.

Here is the general use case I have. The code is in the subdirectory 'src' of the project directory and I anticipate wanting a file in another subdirectory 'subdir' of the project.  The current subroutine I initially wrote is:

```
def path_to(subdir: str, name: str) -> TextIO:
    """Set path to parent then down to subdir with file.ext as name."""
    return pathlib.Path.cwd() / '..' / subdir / name
```

With this calling code it works:

```
def get_files(f, dir1):
    """
    Read file f from changeable subdir dir1.
    """
    file_1 = path_to(dir1, f)
    # Earlier working code without pathlib:
    # file_1 = os.path.join(path + dir1, f)
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(
            file_1,
            encoding="UTF-8",
            infer_datetime_format=True,
            thousands=",",
            index_col=False,
        )
    except FileNotFoundError:
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_save_all)
    return df
```

But this is a special case where I am using the cwd.  What if I were working in a completely different directory?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. `open()` converts a path to an open file. Pathlib is just for dealing with filenames, not the contents.

Comment: Pandas has its own methods to read and write files. `pandas.read_csv` and a dataframe's `to_csv` method are a couple of options. You could use pathlib to build the path and pandas to read the file.